# open file contents in a new browser window

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im trying to open a new browser window with file contents from the server.
But the screen just flashes without opeing the report in a new window.

I do have the correct contents as confirmed in the *network* tab of developer tools.

I have tried a `<a href>` approach, but Im getting a `Not allowed to load local resource:` error. so thought this might work better.

What am I missing here?

**AJAX**

```
openSavedReport:function(data){
    return $.ajax({
        method: "GET",
        url: reportsBaseUrl + "show-report.php",
        data:{name : data}
    }).then(function(data){
        myWindow = window.open("data:text/html," + encodeURIComponent(data), "_blank");
        myWindow.focus();
    });
},
```

**PHP SIDE**

```
$path    = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/reports/saved_reports/";
if(isset($_GET['name'])){
    $name = $_GET['name'].'.html';
    $data = (file_get_contents($path.$name));
    echo json_encode($data);
}
```

Comment: Aside from the clear logic issues, this seems almost entirely pointless. It makes far more sense just to open a new window directly to the URL of the HTML file you want to serve.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Ive tried a `href` approach, but get a `Not allowed to load local resource:` error. so I thought if I could get the contents and open it in a new window it will work.

Answer (score -2):

for security, it's impossible open a new tab/window in an ajax callback function, it means, it's only allowed by a user action.

But, you can create a new tab/window firstly, and then send the ajax request, and set the url/HTML for the tab/window you created before.

my code is:

```
onPayPalClicked() {

    const newTab = window.open()

    const href = window.location.href
    const successURL = href.substr(0, href.lastIndexOf('/'))
      .replace('settlement', 'payment') + '/paypal-return/' + this.orderCode
    const failureURL = href.substr(0, href.lastIndexOf('/'))
      .replace('settlement', 'payment') + '/failure/' + this.orderCode
    this.payPalApiService.function001(this.orderCode, 'USD', successURL, failureURL)
      .then(resp => {
        if ((<any>resp).error.no === 0) {
          this.paypalPaymentURL = (<any>resp).result.approvalUrl
          newTab.location.href = this.paypalPaymentURL
        } else {
          console.error((<any>resp).error.info)
        }
      }).catch(msg => console.error(msg))
}
```